# how to stop djoser from sending activation email when user is updated?

Tags: django, djoser

How to stop djoser from sending an activation email when using "users/me" Base Endpoint with a "put" or "patch" methods??? I have a "Boolean field" inside the user model and I want to make updates for this field using the "users/me" Base Endpoint in djoser, but when I do that, djoser sends an activation email to the user account although it is already activated. please someone help

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.py for djoser may be you set
'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL' to True . Chsnge it false or remove it. May it solve your problem . If not you can tweek some more settings from the docs
https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#send-confirmation-email